# Existence of translations dilations compactifying set

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, compactness

I am reading the book J. Krieger, W. Schlag [*Concentration Compactness for critical Wave Maps*](http://Global%20well-posedness,%20scattering%20and%20blow-up%20for%20the%20energy-critical%20focusing%20non-linear%20wave%20equation), in which one of the key preliminary reductions is Corollary 9.36 on pg. 315, which I have reproduced below.

> **Corollary 9.36** There exist continuous functions $\bar{x} : I \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\lambda : I \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ so that the family of functions $\{\lambda(t)^{-1}\Psi_{\alpha}^{\infty}(t,(\cdot-\bar{x}(t))\lambda(t)^{-1})\}_{t\in I}\subset L_{x}^{2}$ is pre-compact.

Since I believe my issue can be stated without specifying exactly what the function $\Psi_{\alpha}^{\infty}$ defined on the interval $I$ is, I will not do so. Also, I am content with showing the existence of (possibly) discontinuous functions $\bar{x}$ and $\lambda$.

The proof of Corollary 9.36 is by contradiction. I.e. the authors first assume that there do not even exist discontinuous such functions $\bar{x}$, $\lambda$, from which they claim

> there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence of times $\{t_{n}\}\subset I$ so that
>   $$\inf_{\lambda>0, \bar{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{2}}\|\lambda^{-1}\Psi_{\alpha}^{\infty}(t_{n}, (\cdot-\bar{x})\lambda^{-1})-\Psi_{\alpha}^{\infty}(t_{m},\cdot)\|_{2}\geq\varepsilon \tag{*}$$
>   for any $n\neq m$.

I do not see why ( * ) follows from the authors' assumption. I looked at the cited works [14] and [15] in the proof, but these papers did not answer my question, as they state ( * ). I have been struggling with this issue for a while now and would appreciate any clarification.